# In Google Earth Engine (GEE) what is the difference between ConfusionMatrix() and errorMatrix()?

Tags: google-earth-engine, confusion-matrix

In the process of evaluating the classification of a satellite image, it is verified that the GEE has two available commands: ConfusionMatrix() and errorMatrix(). In some literature I see that both represent the same thing, but why does GEE use these two terms? is there any difference between them, for my final result which is the most important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConfusionMatrix` is the model-based confusion matrix of one specific model.  This is also called the re-substitution confusion matrix, as its the result of applying the model to the training data that went into creating the model.

`ErrorMatrix` is the more general version that compares any two properties.